# Button differentiation in android

Tags: android

I am new to android.I am developing an application in that i have two buttons in 1 screen.I have to perform to different actions based on the particular button clicked.I have to differentiate according to which button is clicked.

```
public void showSelectedNumber(int type, String number)
{


         --->Here i have to set two conditions:
    1.This for call
         try 
         {
    //     Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);      //Call options
    //////     Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    //////     while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    //////         String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
    //////     }
    //     callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+number));    
    //     startActivity(callIntent);


    This is for SMS:

        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("sms:"                         //sms options
                + number)));
         }
         catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) 
         {
         Log.e("helloandroid dialing example", "Call failed", e);
         }
        Toast.makeText(this, type + ": " + number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
    }
    }
```

Comment: what you want me to do? pls can be more descriptive?

Comment: Hi  vnshetty   My problem is in the above code "ShowSelectedNumber" in that there are 2 lines this is for call and this is for sms.I have to differntiate this two sections.But i have only 2 buttons nothing other than else.So how can i differntiate this by using that button clicked.

Comment: you can write different method for call and sms no? what is the problem in that and implement click listener by referencing any answer below..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Implement** `onClickListener` in your activity class. And then register it with both buttons..

```
buttonCall.setOnClickListener(this);
buttonSMS.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Now, on `onClick()` method

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
 switch (v.getId())
  {
   case R.id.buttonCall: // id of your call button
   // Call button click..
   break;

   case R.id.buttonSMS:  // id of your SMS button
   // SMS button click
   break; 
  }
}
```

Above code is just for understanding, Real code may be different..

Answer (score 0):

I implement OnClickListener and have something like this in my class

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.smsButton) {
        //call your send sms method
    } 
    if (v.getId() == R.id.callButton) {
        //use you call method
    }
}
```

remember to set the listeners on the 2 buttons as well, set it to the object which has the above method.  I often do this on the onCreate method

```
    View smsButton = findViewById(R.id.smsButton);
    smsButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View callButton = findViewById(R.id.callButton);
    callButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

use id of buttons just like

```
R.id.button1
R.id.button2
```

in

```
onClik(View v){
int id=v.getId();
showSelectedNumber(id,number);
}
```

and in your methos use

```
public void showSelectedNumber(int type,String num){
switch (type)
  {
   case R.id.buttonCall: // id of your call button
   // Call button click..
   break;

   case R.id.buttonSMS:  // id of your SMS button
   // SMS button click
   break; 
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 
    Button smsButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.smsButton);
    smsButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button callButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.callButton);
    callButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
     switch (view.getId())
     {
       case R.id.buttonCall: // id of your call button
               // Call button click code
            break;
       case R.id.buttonSMS:  // id of your SMS button
              // SMS button click code
            break;
      }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can easily do it by fetching button id and the set on click listener to it. 

IN your on create write this.

Button btn_sms = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_sms);
Button btn_call = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_call);

btn_sms..setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);      //Call options
             Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
             while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                 String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
             }
             callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+number));    
             startActivity(callIntent);

                }
        });

btn_call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("sms:" + number)));
          }
          catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) 
          {
              Log.e("helloandroid dialing example", "Call failed", e);
          }
          Toast.makeText(this, type + ": " + number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
        }
    });
```